# How to get all items in multi list in bottle?

Tags: python, bottle

I have a form that allows me to add to a multi list using js. I want to be able to post all the data in that list to my bottle server, but I am not able to get any of the data in there. How do I get all the items in my  statement to be posted to server.py? How do I access this post data once it is posted?

Relevant code:

server.py:

```
@bottle.route('/saveList', method='POST')
def save_list():
    forms = bottle.request.get('the_list')
    print forms # returns 'None'
    return bottle.redirect('/updatelist') # just redirects to the same page with a new list
```

list.tpl

```
 <select multiple="multiple" id="the_list" name="the_list">
     %for item in my_ list:
     <option>{{item}}</option>
     %end
 </select>
```

EDIT:

I am trying to get the whole list, not just the selected values. The user adds to the multi by way of textfield, button, and JS; so I want to get all the values (or all the new values).

EDIT 2:

I used the answers provided along with some js to get the desired result:

```
$('.add_to_the_list').click(function (e) {
...
var new_item = $('<option>', {
                value: new_item_str,
                text: new_item_str,
                class: "new_item" // the money-maker!
            });
...

function selectAllNewItem(selectBoxId) {
    selectBox = document.getElementById(selectBoxId);
    for (var i = 0; i < selectBox.options.length; i++) {
        if (selectBox.options[i].className === "new_item") { // BOOM!
            selectBox.options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}

...
    $('#submit_list').click(function (e) {
        selectAllNewBG("the_list")
    });
```

Comment: You are trying to get POST data, retrieve it from `bottle.request.POST`. `bottle.request.POST.get('the_list')` should work for you. You might also have to assign values for the options, i.e.  `<option value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>`

Comment: That still returns "None."

Comment: I added an answer that shows working code, instead of .get, use .getall.

Comment: try `request.POST.getlist('the-list')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close; just try this instead:

```
all_selected = bottle.request.forms.getall('the_list')
```

You'll want to use [request.forms](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#http-request-methods) and [getall](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#introducing-formsdict).  `request.forms` returns a MultiDict, which is the appropriate data structure for storing multiple selected options.  `getall` is how you retrieve the list of values from a MultiDict:

```
for choice in all_selected:
    # do something with choice
```

or, more simply:

```
for selected in bottle.request.forms.getall('the_list'):
    # do something with selected
```

Comment: How do I getall regardless of selected or not?

Comment: Looks like you arrived at a solution--cool.  (Your web app will only receive selected options, as you discovered.)

Answer (score 2):

To get multiple values back use .getall. Here is the code I was able use this with.

```
import bottle

@bottle.route('/saveList', method='POST')
def save_list():
    forms = bottle.request.POST.getall('the_list')
    print forms 
    return bottle.redirect('/updatelist')

@bottle.route('/updatelist')
@bottle.view('index')
def index():
    return {}

bottle.run()
```

The HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/saveList">
             <select multiple="multiple" id="the_list" name="the_list">
                 <option value="1">Item 1</option>
                 <option value="2">Item 2</option>
                 <option value="3">Item 3</option>
             </select>
            <input type="submit" />
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output to stdout looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2014 13:36:58] "GET /updatelist HTTP/1.1" 200 366
['1', '2']
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2014 13:37:00] "POST /saveList HTTP/1.1" 303 0
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2014 13:37:00] "GET /updatelist HTTP/1.1" 200 366
[]
```

First time selected two objects, second time didn't select any.

Comment: This is ALMOST what I was trying to do. How do I get all the items in the list whether or not they were selected? Do I need to have some js select everything before submitting?

Comment: That is an option, however because you already have those items that you are going to generate the list off of, you can make your life a lot simpler. Off the top of my head: If they are static items I would simply pull them from a global variable in both functions. If they are dynamic, I would define a hidden input, that simply lists the options separated my commas, then grab that and do a .split(",") on it.

Comment: That's probably a better idea. ATM, I have js select everything and submit. I can't change the blue highlight color to make it white (giving the illusion that I'm not doing something very stupid). I'll probably have to change this later.